# Arbitrary precision with dates in Rails and MongoDB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, date, time

What would be a good way of storing date/time data with various precisions in a single field or attribute. For example, if I had a Movie class with a release_date property, and sometimes it would be a specific date like 2012-12-24, and other times it may just be 1948, with no month or day. Ruby doesn't allow for zero-value date parts.

My only good idea so far has been to store the data polymorphicly with another field storing the time as either Number or Time, and the date value would always be stored as an integer, but even that seems really ugly. Other than that all I can think of is storing each data part separately, but that sounds like it would make sorting a nightmare.

Perhaps there's a common way of doing this that I'm unaware of.

Comment: What solution did you end up using?

Comment: Partial-date looks like it would work well if I added in the necessary Mongoid bits to help with storing and recall from the DB. Shouldn't be too bad since it can convert to/from an integer out of the box. There were a few peculiar things about the gem, though, that I need to look into more before I pull the trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [partial-date](http://rubygems.org/gems/partial-date) gem.

> A simple date class that can be used to store partial date values in a
>   single column/attribute. An example use case would include an archive,
>   or catalogue entry where the complete date is unknown. Year is
>   optional and can be a negative value. Month and day are optional, but
>   month must be set before day
>
> PartialDate::Date uses a 30 bit register as the backing store for
>   date instances, and bit fiddling to get or set year, month and day values.